# Can we write a stored function inside a stored procedure in Mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can we **write a stored function inside a stored procedure ? in Mysql**.  Is it possible? If possible any examples for calling the function from that stored procedure?

I want to **write a stored function inside a stored procedure and call it inside the stored procedure.**

Comment: Do you want to create function inside the stored procedure?

Comment: @Code-Monk : Yes, I want to create the function inside that stored procedure and call it from the same stored procedure.

Comment: MySQL doesn't allows to create functions from with in another stored procedures.

Comment: You have to create the function explicitly , then you can call it from the procedure.

Comment: @Code-Monk : I got it. we have to create the function explicitly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes you can do that.
Suppose you have a `stored procedure` as:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE country_hos(IN con CHAR(20), out Name)
BEGIN
SELECT Name, HeadOfState FROM Country
WHERE Continent = con;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

And you want to call this `stored procedure` under other `stored procedure`

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE country_hos2(IN con CHAR(20))
BEGIN

call country_hos('Europe', @result);
set xyz := select @result;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Now you can use the value return from `country_hos` as @result in `country_hos2`

Comment: this is not what he asked.

Comment: @Gaurav : Great effort... I want to know that, is it possible to create a stored function inside a stored procedure in mysql and call it from the same procedure.

Comment: @Gaurav: Anyway this is useful for me.

Comment: this is not the answer. He wants a function inside stored

Comment: @ichimaru: Read above comment from Bibin, he said anyways this is useful for him. Is it you who want more specific solution ?